# Generic test suite for ASP.NET Membership/Role/Profile/Session Providers

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-membership, specifications

I've just created custom ASP.NET Membership, Role, Profile and Session State providers, and I was wondering whether there exists a test suite or something similar to test the implementation of the providers. I've checked some of the open source providers I could find (like the NauckIt.PostgreSQL provider), but neither of them contained unit tests, and all of the forum topics I've found mentioned only a few test cases (like checking whether creating a user works), but this is clearly not a complete test suite for a Membership provider. (And I couldn't find anything for the other three providers)

Are there more or less complete test suites for the above mentioned providers, or are there custom providers out there that have at least some testing avaialable?

Comment: Sounds like a codeplex project waiting to happen...

Comment: @SztupY:  Did you ever come across a test suite for the ASP.NET Membership stuff?  Did you implement it yourself?  I could sure use it.

Comment: @Steve Elmer: never had the time to do it, and I still haven't found one

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there is no such open test suite for providers.

Perhaps you can start one on codeplex...

Comment: this answer is the same as the comment above